# Symfony2: How solve two bundles requirements conflicts when using composer?

Tags: symfony, dependencies, bundle, composer-php

I'm needing to use two bundles:

- [dsyph3r/google-geolocation-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/dsyph3r/google-geolocation-bundle)
- [mlpz/postmark-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/mlpz/postmark-bundle)

I'm having problems when trying to update composer because they have different requirements about **kriswallsmith/buzz** bundle:

1. kriswallsmith/buzz: <=0.5
2. kriswallsmith/buzz: >=0.9

What is the best way to solve this issue? Do I have to report an issue in bundle github Issue tracker? Or is better to fork google-geolocation-bundle to update its dependencies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try to use a not real buzz version number in composer like this:

```
"kriswallsmith/buzz": "v0.9 as 0.5"
```

But it's not a fact it will be working, because it could be that `google-geolocation-bundle` doesn't really work with higher versions of buzz.

But also try to use something instead of `dsyph3r/google-geolocation-bundle`. It is very strange it requires an old version of the bundle...

Comment: Fine! Works perfect! Thanks Hast.

Comment: Why did you change your answer? "v0.9 as dev-master" is not working while "v0.9 as 0.5" is!

Comment: @HugoMagalhães sorry, I just was confused with something. I changed it back :)